# array_diff in php returning only one unmatched value even if it is not duplicate

Tags: php, arrays

While running below code array_diff is returning only one value. However it should return two values. My first array holds:

```
access.2018.08.09.log
access.2018.08.10.log
access.2018.08.12.log
```

My second array holds:

```
access.2018.08.09.log
```

`array_diff()` is returning only: `access.2018.08.12.log`

Can someone please guide why is it happening.

```
<?php
$files = scandir('C:\wamp64\www\MyLogs\logsfiles');
foreach($files as $file) {
    if($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;

    $S1=array($file.PHP_EOL);
    print_r($S1);
}
$S2 =explode("\n", file_get_contents('uplodedregistry.txt'));
$result = array_diff_assoc($S1, $S2);

print_r($result);       
?>
```

Comment: You are overwriting your `$S1` variable, it will therefor only look for the difference in the last element (because there is only one). Make `$S1` an array and append to that instead

Comment: thanks much. Can you please explain how to do that. I can see S1 is already an array. Please bear with my silly questions, its just i am new to php.

Answer (score 0):

You keep overwriting your `$S1` variable - so at the end of the loop, it will only hold one element - the last value from your loop. Instead, instantiate the array before the loop, and append to it inside the loop.

```
<?php
$files = scandir('C:\wamp64\www\MyLogs\logsfiles');
$S1 = array(); // Init the array here
foreach($files as $file) {
    if($file == '.' || $file == '..')
        continue;

    $S1[] = $file.PHP_EOL; // Append to $S1
}
$S2 = explode("\n", file_get_contents('uplodedregistry.txt'));
$result = array_diff($S1, $S2);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: But this code will create 2 arrays. See the result:- C:\wamp64\www\MyLogs\test.php:9:
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'access.2018.08.09.log
' (length=23)
C:\wamp64\www\MyLogs\test.php:9:
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'access.2018.08.09.log
' (length=23)
  1 => string 'access.2018.08.12.log
' (length=23)

Comment: Yes, `array_diff()` checks for the difference between two arrays, so you need both to be an array. Here you'll check for elements in `$S1` that are different from (that does not exist in) `$S2`. See https://3v4l.org/KkM2A - which means that if you're getting a different result than this, you must check `$S1` and `$S2` for which exact values you're actually dealing with.

Comment: These are the files present in my directory from where $S1 is taking its value: access.2018.08.09.log, access.2018.08.12.log . And $S2 takes its value from uplodedregistry.txt file which has just one entry access.2018.08.09.log. So, logically it should return only access.2018.08.12.log but when i run the code it is returning both the files

Comment: In the above code when i am doing print_r($S1), it is giving me 2 arrays- one is of size 1 holding value:access.2018.08.09.log and another array of size 2 holding 2 values: access.2018.08.09.log and access.2018.08.12.log